# Error in setting lastmodifieddate in Java

Tags: java, file, ftp, timestamp, last-modified

I tried to set the lastmodifeddate of local folder file as the lastmodifieddate of FTP file.
But, in the return value it returns false and date is also not set properly.

Here is the function,

```
 public static void getModifiedDateAndTimeFromFTPFile(String FTPHost, String FTPUserName, String FTPPassword, String FTPRemoteDirectory, String localFilePath, String fileName) {
        try{
            //get Local File 
            File fileLocal = new File(localFilePath + fileName);

            //Connect to FTP and get the lastmodified time of File.
            FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
            client.connect(FTPHost);
            client.login(FTPUserName, FTPPassword);
            client.changeWorkingDirectory(FTPRemoteDirectory);          
            FTPFile ftpFile = client.listFiles(fileName)[0];

            //Get last_modified date of FTP file.
            Date ftpFileDate = ftpFile.getTimestamp().getTime();

            //Now set date to the Local File.
            boolean boolSetTime = fileLocal.setLastModified(ftpFileDate.getTime());
            System.out.println("    Was last modified time set successfully ? : " + boolSetTime);           
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error : " + ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

Can anybody help me by pointing out my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried echoing ftpFileDate.getTime()? Also, do you have permissions to the file in question?

Comment: Yes I do have permission to access file, even I can download the file.

Comment: I also tried to print ftpFileDate.getTime() and it returns the correct lastmodifed date.

Comment: I got solution. Path separator was reason. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably `localFilePath + fileName` do not form the intended filename. This won't give you a exception when constructing a File object, but `setLastModified(...)` would always return false on a non-existing file.

May be it's just a missing path separator?

Comment: I got solution, path separator was the reason, for it. Otherwise function was good. Thanks for suggestion.